# Form submit not always passing button value

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on the **ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile Application**.

Problem is that background code behaves different when application is tested on mobile based web browsers and windows or mac based web browsers. Here are the details:

I have 4 buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="actionButton" value="START" id="a1" />
<input type="submit" name="actionButton" value="BACK" id="a2" />
<input type="submit" name="actionButton" value="NEXT" id="a3" />
<input type="submit" name="actionButton" value="FINISH" id="a4" />
```

And in my controller i have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SurveyModel model, string actionButton)
```

When i test this on the **windows** or **mac** based **browsers** it works fine. START, BACK, NEXT, FINISH values are passed to the actionButton parameter when FORM is submitted and i can handle them without any problems.

When i test this on the **iPhone**, and submit the form by clicking on the one of the buttons above, sometimes the actionButton parameter is empty. Anyone had a same experience?

Comment: I'm seeing this too but with button tags in a jQuery Mobile application. Did you ever figure it out?